# Multiline values in a cell to single line separated_python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, cell

I have a df where values from the first cell of column 'col2' are not in a single line but in multilines as per the following example:

```
col1   col2
ID1    value1
       value2
       value3
ID2    value4, value5, value6
```

I want to bring them in a single line as in the example for ID2, single line with any separator between them.
Is there a way to do that with python?

my df:

[image]

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': ['value1\nvalue2\nvalue3', 'value4, value5, value6']})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
df['col2']=df['col2'].replace('\n',',',regex=True)
```

OR

If you wanted to replace all occurances of `'\n'` to `','` then use:

```
df=df.replace('\n',',',regex=True)
```

output of `df`:

```
    col1    col2
0   1       value1,value2,value3
1   2       value4, value5, value6
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
df['col1']=df['col1'].fillna(method='ffill')
gr=df.groupby('col1')['col2'].agg(list)
gr=gr.reset_index()
gr['col2']=gr['col2'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x) if type(x) == list else x)

>>> print(gr)

  col1                  col2
0  ID1  value1,value2,value3
1  ID2  value4,value5,value6
```

Comment: Thank you but returns this error TypeError: Cannot reset_index inplace on a Series to create a DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

For each column (assuming you may have multiple columns that may have this similar data), just use `df[col].replace(target,toBeReplaced,regex=True)`, and all the rows of that column having that `target` in it will be replaced with the `toBeReplaced`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': ['value1\nvalue2\nvalue3', 'value4, value5, value6']})

for col in list(df):
    df[col] = df[col].replace('\n',',',regex=True)

print(df)
```